# How to check if email is verified in Firebase using a parameter?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My plan is to ONLY sign in a user if the email has been verified. I am using a if-statement to check if the email is verified using the built in "emailVerified" function but it is crashing.

```
function login(email, password) {
  if (email.emailVerified) {
    console.log("trying to log user");
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  } else {
    console.log("failed to log user");
    alert("Please verify your email");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine whether a profile's `emailVerified` property is set in the client-side SDK without signing in. So with only the client-side SDK, you won't be able to do what your pseudo-code does.

What you *can* do is create a custom API in a trusted environment (for example on Cloud Functions) where you use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to [get a user profile by its email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) and then check if its `emailVerified` property is set to true. You can then call this custom API from within your application code. But this still won't prevent a malicious user from calling the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method themselves

Alternatively, and much simpler, is to sign in first, then check if the email is verified, and only allow the user to continue using the app (and accessing data) if the email is verified.

Note that this topic comes up quite regularly, so I recommend also reading:

- [Only let pre-verified users log into Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343031/only-let-pre-verified-users-log-into-firebase)
- [Firebase - Auth - discover users who signed up but not verified email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906959/firebase-auth-discover-users-who-signed-up-but-not-verified-email/37908433#37908433)
- [Firebase Auth - createUserWithEmailAndPassword() - prevent login until email is verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762736/firebase-auth-createuserwithemailandpassword-prevent-login-until-email-is/57763128#57763128)
- [Can I get updated emailVerified without logging out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874910/can-i-get-updated-emailverified-without-logging-out)
- and more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-authentication%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20only%20verified)